# Jquery Autocomplete() / Catcomplete() Function not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am unable to see the catcomplete autocomplete intellisense when I fetch it from my web service using the below code . My web service return the below string

```
[{label:"TechCrunch",category:"Website"},{label:"Techcrunch",category:"Tag"},      {label:"techno",category:"Tag"}] 


 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#<%= txtinputtag.ClientID%>").catcomplete({
      source: function(request,response){//error if I hard code this ajax call will with a an array works fine 
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   url: "../Tag/Follow.aspx/GetIntellisense",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: "{'searchtext':'" + request.term + "'}",
                   success: function (data) {
                       if (data.d != "") {
                           //console.log(data.d);//this show the desired json output as returned from the web service
                            response(data.d);
                       }
                   }
               });
           },
           select: function(event, ui) {
               $(this).val("");
               return false;
           },
       });
   });
```

this is the WebMethod that return a string

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetIntellisense(string searchtext)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        var uc = new UtilityClass();

        List<DTOWebsite> lstDtoWebsites = uc.GetIntellisense(searchtext);

        string str = "[";

        foreach (DTOWebsite dto in lstDtoWebsites)
        {
            str += "{label:\""+dto.WebSiteName +"\",category:\""+dto.WebsiteType +"\"},";

        }
        str = str.Remove(str.Length-1,1);
        str += "]";

        return str.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept 2 parameters in the function that you assign to the `source` parameter:

1. `request` has the `term` for the search
2. `response` is the callback function that you pass the result to

   ```
   source: function(request, response){ ...
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7uahuhx/

Comment: After the above changes it returns me this.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '108' in [{label:"TechCrunch",category:"Website"},{label:"Techcrunch",category:"Tag"},{label:"techno",category:"Tag"}]
I have also updated the question

Comment: @KinnanNawaz it does not look like this error comes from the code in your question. Where do you have the `in` operator in your script?

Comment: I have not declared an "in" operator anywhere it is coming from Jquery i.e. source "jquery-1.10.2.js:985" line 985

Comment: I think I am not making the JSON right in my web-service call